# how Bixby NL process with key word like "of"

Tags: samsung-mobile, bixby, bixbystudio

For example
[g: article] what is (united states of America)[v: words], it will run fine in the simulator, but in a real device, only united states goes to the target value, it happens to other NL too.

Comment: I mean any preposition word we need to pay attention to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this is due to too few utterances trained and/or not enough variety in country name lengths.

In order to increase the likelihood that Bixby picks up the full name of any country, you should train utterances that contain the prepositions you would like to account for.

I attempted it on my end and was able to handle country names with either prepositions and/or multiple words such as "The United States of America", "Serbia and Montenegro", and "The United Kingdom" in addition to single-word country names.